# "Ok" button not appearing in <select> tag on Ionic App

Tags: html, ios, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Ionic app, and for some reason, when I use the  tag, the "Ok" button doesn't appear - please check the screenshot below.

I'm using a `<select>` with `<option>` inside.

Any idea on what may be happening?

[image]

Comment: We need the full code and a screenshot of an instance in which the “Ok” button does appear, as a comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you Tried to do this ?

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

  //Change this to false to return accessory bar 
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

According to [this](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/select-dropdown-issue-on-ios/5573/6), this code could bring back your keyboard accessories.

Comment: This was causing the issue. It's working fine now. I'm not sure why on earth they disable this feature as default on Ionic starter app. Thanks!