# In ios I can not select a dropdown option?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

My code is done in ionic1.
my code works perfect for android but for ios I can not select any option of my dropdown, I have read solutions like this:

["Ok" button not appearing in <select> tag on Ionic App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000359/ok-button-not-appearing-in-select-tag-on-ionic-app)

but it does not work for me. What I can do? This is my code:

```
  <div class="form-group mt-4">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Departamento</label>
        <select class="form-control select_custom select_custom_set" ng-model="selectDepartamento" ng-options="item as item.Nombre for item in aDepartamentos | orderBy:'Nombre' track by item.Codigo" ng-change="fn_updateMun(selectDepartamento)" name="selectDepartamento" required>
          <option value="" style="display:none;">Seleccione departamento</option>
        </select>
  </div>
```

[image]

And this is my configuration:

```
com.googlemaps.ios 2.7.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release 1.4.2 "cordova-android-play- 
services-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 2.1.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.3.6 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.2.3 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 4.0.8 "Diagnostic"
```

My current code:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar 
//above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && 
 window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
 }
 if (window.StatusBar) {
 // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
 StatusBar.styleDefault();
 }
});
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like for the new `cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard`  plugin you need to do this to show the keyboard options.

```
Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);
```

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard) for this plugin.

Comment: thanks for answering, but I am using cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard", look please my current code

Comment: ohh I will try that

Comment: I put the code you said under "cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);" but it not works.. the same problem

Comment: thank you, I realized that I never entered by the if I had. I'm testing in xcode but the keyboard is hidden, I must turn it on from the emulator options, will the same thing happen on a cell phone? thanks

Comment: In the emulator keyboard doesn’t show up always. On device it should work fine.

Comment: Do you have to upgrade to cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard? ionic v1 seems to reference the old way cordova.plugins.Keyboard and the new one uses window.Keyboard. Using cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false) does not work. And other comments say that it's not intended to work with v1? here: https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/issues/38#issuecomment-445470929  - Not sure what I can do? polyfill and try to get it working? Any ideas?